# JQuery & SVG drag and drop

Tags: jquery, svg

Been banging my head against a wall for a couple of days now and getting nowhere, so I just want to find some sort of confirmation that what I'm trying to do is actually do'able....

I have a page with a SVG witin a DIV. I want to be able to click on a component of the SVG and drag it around. Simple really in theory.
I had this in a messy raw javascript version, but am trying to do it in JQuery for consistency.

I had the following, wich drags the entire container DIV around:

*
    var svgName = "/mySvg.svg";

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#svgDiv').svg();
    var svg = $('#svgDiv').svg('get');
    svg.load(svgName,

    function () {
        $('#svgDiv').draggable().bind('mousedown', function(event, ui) {
            $(event.target.parentElement).append( event.target );
        }).bind('drag', function(event, ui) {
            event.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+event.clientX+","+event.clientY+")");
        });
    });
});
```

*

I changed it this this, which I thought would get an element of the SVG by it's ID, but this does nothing. It's as if the JQuery can't see 'inside' (want of a better word) the DIV.
*

```
var svgSource = "/mySvg.svg";

$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#svgDiv').svg();
    var svgObj = $('#svgDiv').svg('get');
    svgObj.load(svgSource,
        function () {
            var svgObj2 = $('#svgDiv').svg('get');
            var svgElem = svgObj2.getElementById('pathIdOne');
            $(svgElem).draggable().bind('mousedown', function(event, ui) {
                $(event.target.parentElement).append( event.target );
            }).bind('drag', function(event, ui) {
                //event.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+event.clientX+","+event.clientY+")");
                event.target.setAttribute('x', ui.position.left);
                event.target.setAttribute('y', ui.position.top);                    
            });
        });
});
```

*

Can anyone see anything glaringly obvious that needs changing, can this be done, or is this just completely wrong?

Comment: Not that many svg elements have 'x' and 'y' attributes, you might have more luck with a 'transform' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I recently spent a couple days hammering at this problem, and I came up with a solution that worked fairly well for me. It's definitely a hack, and won't work in all situations.

[This link](http://www.codedread.com/blog/archives/2005/12/21/how-to-enable-dragging-in-svg/) has an excellent description of how to solve the problem in general, and that is definitely the "better" solution. However, I wanted to keep using JQuery's excellent Draggable API.

You can see a quick mock-up of what I did in a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BFU6F/1/). The key idea is to use a proxy div which you keep hovering exactly over the svg element you want to drag. Then you change the svg element's x and y coordinates as you drag the proxy div. Something like this:

```
$('#proxy').on('drag', function(e)
    {
        t = $('#background');
        prox = $('#proxy');
        t.attr('x', t.attr('x')*1
                   + prox.css('left').slice(0,-2)*1
                   - prox.data('position').left)
            .attr('y', t.attr('y')*1
                      + prox.css('top').slice(0,-2)*1
                      - prox.data('position').top);
        prox.data('position',{top : prox.css('top').slice(0,-2)*1,
                              left: prox.css('left').slice(0,-2)*1}
                  );
    });
```

In my case the SVG element I wanted to drag would always fill a certain square on the screen, so it was very easy to position the proxy div over the target. In other situations it could be much more difficult. It's also not too hard to use the 'containment' option to make sure you don't drag the background outside the frame...it just takes some careful math and you have to reset the containment in between each drag.

To make this applicable to more SVG elements, you could use transforms rather than x and y coordinates.